# Not able to append word document when I am inserting multiple image into word using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I used below code for taking snapshot of screen and save into a word file..
This code is used as button..
but when i take gain a screen shot it replace the existing file..
How can i append this ..pls suggest 
thanks in advance. :)

```
private void btnmanActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    setVisible(false);

    if (btnman.getText().equals("Quick ScreenShot")) {

        try {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Rectangle captureRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1430, 840);
            BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureRect);

            ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, "JPG", new File(path.getText() + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + ".jpg"));
            img = path.getText() + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + ".jpg";
            System.out.println(img);
            setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception es) {
            System.out.println("not done");
        }
    } else {

        try {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Rectangle captureRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1400, 850);
            BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureRect);

            ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, "JPG", new File("E:\\" + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + ".jpg"));
            img = "E:\\" + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + ".jpg";
            System.out.println(img);
            setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception es) {
            System.out.println("not done");
        }


        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

        XWPFParagraph title = doc.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = title.createRun();
        run.setText(path.getText());
        run.setBold(true);
        title.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(img);

            //run.addBreak();
            run.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, img, Units.toEMU(500), Units.toEMU(600));

            //is.close();
            System.out.println(img);
            System.out.print(path.getText());

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path.getText());


            doc.write(fos);
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("Enterd successfully");

        } catch (Exception es) {
            System.err.println("es");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's overwriting the file instead of appending because you are creating a new (empty) XWPFDocument each time

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
```

and saving it using the same (I'm assuming) path.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path.getText());
doc.write(fos);
```

So it ends up replacing the file.

Try using instead:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(path.getText()));
```

To open the previous document if such already exists.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex its so needful.